# Why my triggers can't created in mysql 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I used this in the older version of mysql in php myadmin site:

```
DECLARE @newyear int
SET @newyear = (SELECT year FROM movies)
DECLARE @year int
SET @year = (SELECT year FROM links)
DECLARE @title varchar(50)
SET @title = (SELECT title FROM movies)

update links set year = @newyear where movietitle = @title and year = @year
```

and it worked perfectly.
But I upgraded to mysql 5.7 and now I can't add this code to the site, it gives me error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @newyear int SET @newyear = (SELECT year FROM movies) DECLARE @year' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
# testing data
# CREATE TABLE movies (id INTEGER, year INTEGER, title TEXT);
# CREATE TABLE links (id INTEGER, year INTEGER, movietitle TEXT);

SET @newyear = (SELECT year FROM movies);
SET @year = (SELECT year FROM links);
SET @title = (SELECT title FROM movies);

UPDATE links
SET year = @newyear
WHERE movietitle = @title and year = @year
```

Comment: @user7425848, no errors. Created a SQLFiddle for you: http://rextester.com/NAMNFK97384